# Computing the first eigenfunction of the p-Laplacian in a real interval

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

How can I numerically compute the first (non-negative) eigenfunction $u$ of the $p$-Laplacian ($p>1$) in a bounded interval $(-a,a) \subset \mathbb R$ (up to positive multiplicative constant)?
$$-\Delta_p u = \lambda_1 u^{p-1}, \quad \text{ in } (-a,a),$$
$$u = 0, \quad \text{ in } \partial (-a,a).$$

Also, can Mathematica give us the explicit expression of $\lambda_1$ and $u$ in this case?

Notice this: for the classical Laplacian, I could just write

```
{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 6]
```

But in this question I'm interested

1. in the case of the $p$-Laplacian
2. in getting more precise information (explicit formula) for the specific case of $\Omega$ being a symmetric interval.

Comment: This is a fully nonlinear eigenproblem, i.e., even the differential operator of leading order is not linear. I doubt that _Mathematica_ can do with built-in techniques. @user21 will be more knowledgeable about this.

Comment: So I guess one has to set up a nonlinear optimizer for the $L^p$-Rayleigh quotient. This is certainly possible, but might require some fiddling.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, no this is not possible out of the box, one would need to get one's hands dirty; probably quite dirty...